# Eclipse Build Path Exclusions/Inclusions

Tags: eclipse, classpath

Following the advice in this link, [Eclipse, classpath and subversion](http://francisoud.blogspot.com/2008/07/eclipse-classpath-ad-subversion.html), I have setup my Eclipse project to ignore the Subversion directory.  However, I cannot seem to find where those settings are actually stored.  I want to be able to check them into a repository so, when I move to another computer, I (or a team) will have the settings in place and won't have to worry about the same issue.

Anybody know where I can find these settings?  They do not exist in the project's .classpath or .project file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are stored in a `.classpath` file at the root of your project directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="[a '|' delimited list of excluded dirs]" 
      kind="src" path="[path]"/>
    .....

</classpath>
```

Comment: Wow...I can't believe I missed that.  My eyes must have just skimmed right over it.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

In the .svn directory, there is an entry file.

When you set up the ignore, it is stored in another file, which name I can't remember.